# Deserializing JSON data using Gson

Tags: java, json, deserialization, gson

I was trying to deserialize a JSON string that contains a GeoJSON string.

```
point: {
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [
        7.779259,
        52.21864
    ]
}
```

The object I want to create is of type

```
com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point
```

We use this class because of the use of an PostGis database for spatial data. Unfortunately the class does not have a non-arg constructor, which is needed. But somehow it also implements CoordinateSequence [CoordinateSequence](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/CoordinateSequence.html) which neither has a non-arg constructor. Whenever I try to deserialize the incoming json string I get an error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for 
interface com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.CoordinateSequence. 
Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
```

I tried to create an InstanceCreator for the interface of CoordinateSequence following the example [here](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/InstanceCreator.html) but did not succeed. 
Also subclassing Point did not bring the answer as the problem lies in the used interface of CoordinateSequence.

I would be thankful for any help or hints, that lead me to the solution.

Comment: Can you extend com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point class with your own with default constructor, and serialize/deserialize them?

Comment: Hi Alexey,
thanks for your comment. I already tried extending Point. Please see my comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved it using the Custom JsonDeserializer. Of course this is just a quick and dirty solution. One should check for other types and errors. But this should give an idea.

```
public class GeometryDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Geometry> {

@Override
public Geometry deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeofT,
        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

    String type = json.getAsJsonObject().get("type").toString();

    JsonArray coordinates = json.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("coordinates");

    GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory(null);
    Coordinate coord = new Coordinate(coordinates.get(0).getAsDouble(), coordinates.get(1).getAsDouble());
    Geometry point = geometryFactory.createPoint(coord);


    return point;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the class is from a library that you cant change. Did you try subclassing the class and putting a no-arg constructor in your subclass just to assist the serialization process? I have done that before with some success.

```
// .... content I cant change.
public class LibraryPOJOClass {
  public LibraryPOJOClass(final int id) { 
    // ...
  }
}

public class MyLibraryPojoClass extends LibraryPOJOClass {
  MyLibraryPojoClass() {
    super(0); // I will change this later, with reflection if need be. 
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Robert, 
thanks for your answer. But unfortunately I already tried subclassing. It seems that not Point itself is the problem, but more the used interface of CoordinateSequence which I can't touch.

Answer (score 0):

Do it server side:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"Point","coordinates":[7.779259,52.21864]}');
```

Note: the example provided in the question looks slightly different than [The GeoJSON Format Specification](http://www.geojson.org/geojson-spec.html).

Comment: Hi Mike, 
that would work if the Point object is the only object you want to persist. But the Point is embedded in another object.